# Arrow function error: Object is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I try to use an arrow function with {} it seems to think it's an object and throw an error. I thought this is how arrow functions are generally defined?

The error given for the code below is `TypeError: #<Object> is not a function`

```
let allProperties = [];

sites.forEach(site => site.properties.forEach(p => {if (!allProperties.find(p)) allProperties.push(p)} ));
```

Edit: sites might be defined similarly to the following:

```
sites = [
{
    "properties": [
        { "id": "111-11", "display": "Zone", "value": 1 },
    ]
}];
```

Comment: What is `sites`? Please post a snippet which can reproduce your error.

Comment: If you use the {} with => you need to use the return statement. It only implicitly returns the value if you provide a single expression after =>, not if you provide a block

Comment: Thank you, that explains the discrepancy. I'm not really trying to return anything though, just push to a new list. I'm new to JavaScript and I'm a little confused.

Comment: Did that fix your problem? I wasn't sure if it would, I just wanted to explain that bit of functionality because in your question you seemed unsure of how it worked.

Comment: After thinking over it for a second I still don't know where to go. My goal isn't to return a value, but rather push a value to an array while inside the function. I edited my comment as you posted, sorry.

Comment: The code you posted works, except for the unknown part of `allProperties`. There is no need for a return statement in an arrow function.

Comment: It's simply defined as an empty array so that seems odd... I added that to the post.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down. Check out my answer and see if that does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's barking at `if(!allProperties.find(p))`.  It's not liking the `.find()` because you have supplied it with an object as a parameter, not a function. [.find() Docs Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

If you change it to `if (allProperties.indexOf(p) === -1) {...}` it works as expected.

```js
var allProperties = [];
var sites = [
{
    "properties": [
        { "id": "111-11", "display": "Zone", "value": 1 },
    ]
}];

sites.forEach(site => site.properties.forEach(p => {
 if (allProperties.indexOf(p) === -1) {
  allProperties.push(p);
 }
}));

console.log(allProperties);
```

Comment: Ohhh I think find wants a function, not an object to match with.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the function you want is `allProperties.contains(p)`. But this is recent, so older browsers won't support it.

Comment: @Barmar Can you post documentation for .contains()? I see array.prototype.includes(), but I can't seem to find .contains() anywhere

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects a callback function as first parameter, which is not what you supply and probably not thought of.

Comment: Ya this was apparently the issue. I appreciate the help!